# Query a table using data from another table

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

I'm new to JavaScript Promise and i'm trying to do a pretty complex (for me) thing.
I have a mysql table with some values AND id's that i need to extract and use them to query another table.
From all this i need to create JSON string and send it in Express res.send().

im able to use Promise to query data and it's working great but in this case i need to get the id from column 'contact_id' and query the 'contacts' table by the 'contact_id' as primary key and get the full information about the contact ('name', 'contact number', etc...)

this is the code im using to extract some other data from other tables that i have in my project:

```
here's my tables:

'contact_relation' table looks like this:

record_id|patient_id|contact_id|relation|
---------|----------|----------|--------|
        2|1         |         1|Wife    |
       12|1         |         2|dauther |


i need to extract the 'contact_id' and then query the 'contacts' table.

'contacts' table:

id|first_name|last_name|address   |contact_phone_1|contact_number_2|
--|----------|---------|----------|---------------|----------------|
 1|Sara      |Connor   |somestreet|04-002211      |056-0560564     |
```

```
database.query( `SELECT * FROM patient_general_data WHERE patient_id='${data_request_id}'` )
    .then( rows => {
        basic_data = rows;
        return database.query( `SELECT * FROM patient_prescriptions WHERE patient_id='${data_request_id}'` );
    } )
    .then( rows => {
        patient_prescriptions = rows;
        return database.query( `SELECT * FROM patient_contact_relation WHERE patient_id='${data_request_id}'` );
    } )
    .then( rows => {
        patient_contacts = rows;
        return database.query( `SELECT * FROM patient_personal_doctors WHERE patient_id='${data_request_id}'` );
    } )
    .then ( rows =>{
        patient_personal_doctors = rows;
        return database.close();
    })
    .then( () => {

        medicalRecord = [{
            patient_id : basic_data[0].patient_id,
            patient_first_name : basic_data[0].patient_first_name,
            patient_contacts_data : contacts_obj_ready,
            patient_personal_doctors : patient_personal_doctors
            patient_contacts : patient_contacts
        }]

        res.send(medicalRecord[0]);
    } );
```

by the end i need to get something like this (if possible):

```
medicalRecord = [{
            patient_id : basic_data[0].patient_id,
            patient_first_name : basic_data[0].patient_first_name,
            patient_contacts_data : contacts_obj_ready,
            patient_personal_doctors : patient_personal_doctors
            patient_contacts : [{
                 // filling the data from some object with data
                 contact_relation: "wife",
                 contact_info: {
                    first_name: "sara",
                    last_name: "connor",
                    address: "..."
                    ....
                    ...
                 }
            }]
}]
```

Comment: Once you have mastered SQL joins, you will be able to compose a single SQL query and get all the required data in one shot.

Comment: Whichever approach you take for gathering the data, tunnelling into it and repackaging in the format you want is a matter knowing what you want and working at it. You know your data better than anyone here.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 eventually i accomplished this with JOIN. i did some clever JOINS on the tables and got exactly the data that i needed in the format that i wanted.
Thanks..

Comment: Hey, well done, I was expecting you still to need to massage the data in Javascript. You now know more than I ever did about joins. They used to drive me nuts. If I tried one now, I'd need to go back to basics. Pleased to have pointed you in the right direction.